# Firebase Initialisation Error : React Native 71 or 72 + Google Services 4.4.0 plugin but works in 4.3.15

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-play-services, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

Google Services (Project build Gradle) : classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'

Firebase Perf :  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.5.0'

Below Exception throws at app initialisation:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sample, PID: 32664
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.(ConfigResolver.java:78)
at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getInstance(ConfigResolver.java:86)
at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.(AppStateMonitor.java:98)
at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.getInstance(AppStateMonitor.java:87)
at com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.NetworkRequestMetricBuilder.(NetworkRequestMetricBuilder.java:92)
at com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.NetworkRequestMetricBuilder.builder(NetworkRequestMetricBuilder.java:84)
at com.google.firebase.perf.network.InstrumentOkHttpEnqueueCallback.(InstrumentOkHttpEnqueueCallback.java:42)
at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.enqueue(FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.java:73)
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.PackagerStatusCheck.run(PackagerStatusCheck.java:51)
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper.isPackagerRunning(DevServerHelper.java:483)
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerBase$19.run(DevSupportManagerBase.java:850)
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerBase.isPackagerRunning(DevSupportManagerBase.java:856)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner(ReactInstanceManager.java:451)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground(ReactInstanceManager.java:417)
at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:512)
at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:481)
at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.loadApp(ReactDelegate.java:103)
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.loadApp(ReactActivityDelegate.java:111)
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(ReactActivityDelegate.java:106)
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:46)
at com.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8397)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8370)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1403)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3841)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4010)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:111)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2466)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8381)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.sample. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:179)
at com.google.firebase.perf.config.RemoteConfigManager.getInitialStartupMillis(RemoteConfigManager.java:91)
at com.google.firebase.perf.config.RemoteConfigManager.(RemoteConfigManager.java:85)
at com.google.firebase.perf.config.RemoteConfigManager.(RemoteConfigManager.java:52)
at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.(ConfigResolver.java:78) 
at com.google.firebase.perf.config.ConfigResolver.getInstance(ConfigResolver.java:86) 
at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.(AppStateMonitor.java:98) 
at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.getInstance(AppStateMonitor.java:87) 
at com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.NetworkRequestMetricBuilder.(NetworkRequestMetricBuilder.java:92) 
at com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.NetworkRequestMetricBuilder.builder(NetworkRequestMetricBuilder.java:84) 
at com.google.firebase.perf.network.InstrumentOkHttpEnqueueCallback.(InstrumentOkHttpEnqueueCallback.java:42) 
at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.enqueue(FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.java:73) 
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.PackagerStatusCheck.run(PackagerStatusCheck.java:51) 
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper.isPackagerRunning(DevServerHelper.java:483) 
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerBase$19.run(DevSupportManagerBase.java:850) 
at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerBase.isPackagerRunning(DevSupportManagerBase.java:856) 
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner(ReactInstanceManager.java:451) 
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground(ReactInstanceManager.java:417) 
at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:512) 
at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:481) 
at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.loadApp(ReactDelegate.java:103) 
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.loadApp(ReactActivityDelegate.java:111) 
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(ReactActivityDelegate.java:106) 
at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:46) 
at com.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8397) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8370) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1403) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3841) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4010) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:111) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2466) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8381) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)

Upgraded Google Services in Project build gradle, leads crash rather than working fine.